# How to exit VSTO add-in

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there a better way to close VSTO add-in for Outlook 2010 from the add-in code than throwing an exception?

I don't like to throw exception because Outlook may think that my add-in is not stable.

---Edit:---

By close I mean stop execution of the add-in code and hiding its UI or its deactivation. But I want it to be enabled after restart of the Outlook

Comment: What do you mean by close? Disabling it? Closing a panel?

Comment: by close I mean stop execution of the add-in code and hiding it's UI or its deactivation. But I want it to be enabled after restart of the Outlook

Answer (score 3):

When you create your VSTO project in VS2010, the following code should be automatically generated in you `ThisAddIn.cs`. If not, you might want to add them in yourself.

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InternalStartup()
{
     this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
     this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
}

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //execute your code here, e.g. output some values to a text file 
}
```

You can place your code in ThisAddIn_Shutdown event, and executing it only when add-in is shutting down.

EDIT:
Here's what MSDN says:

> Starting in Outlook 2010, Outlook, by default, does not signal add-ins
>   that it is shutting down. Specifically, Outlook no longer calls the
>   OnBeginShutdown and OnDisconnection methods of the IDTExtensibility2
>   interface during fast shutdown. Similarly, an Outlook add-in written
>   with Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office no longer calls the
>   ThisAddin_Shutdown method when Outlook is shutting down.

More details in here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee720183.aspx#OL2010AdditionalShutdownChanges_AddinShutdownChangesinOL2010Beta

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I actually want is to trigger ThisAddIn_Shutdown event. Do you have ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void UnloadAddInManually()
{
    //Try find our Add-In...
    foreach (COMAddIn comAddIn in this.Application.COMAddIns)
    {
        if (comAddIn.ProgId.Contains("< ADDIN_PROG_ID >"))
        {
            //Found Add-In: Unload it...
            comAddIn.Connect = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working in EXCEL for me.

Note: You can find your < ADDIN_PROG_ID > when you have a look under "Settings > Add-Ins > COM-Add-Ins" in your office host application.

Comment: Great! I use this code in order to shut down my plugin in case someone refuses end user license ;-)