# VSTO Plugin Gets Disabled even after start event completed within 0.2 seconds

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have developed an Outlook VSTO plugin. Outlook is showing it as disabled plugin.

Here's `ThisAddin` Start Event Code

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    log.Info("ThisAddIn_Startup START");

    OutlookApplication = this.Application as Outlook.Application;
    currentExplorer = OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
    mainInspectors = OutlookApplication.Inspectors;

    OutlookApplication.Startup += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_StartupEventHandler(Application_Startup);
            
    OutlookApplication.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookApplication_ItemSend);
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
            
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder deletedFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
    deletedItems = deletedFolder.Items;
    deletedItems.ItemAdd += DeletedItems_ItemAdd;
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deletedFolder);

    Outlook.MAPIFolder sentFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    sentItems = sentFolder.Items;
    sentItems.ItemAdd += SentItems_ItemAdd;
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sentFolder);

    Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    InboxItems = inboxFolder.Items;
    InboxItems.ItemAdd += InboxItems_ItemAdd;

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxFolder);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookNs);

    log.Info("ThisAddIn_Startup END");
}
```

Here's Log.

```
2022-12-26 17:03:34,784 [VSTA_Main] INFO  - ThisAddIn_Startup START
2022-12-26 17:03:34,825 [VSTA_Main] INFO  - ThisAddIn_Startup END
```

I am expecting to start plugin normally without going into Disabled Addin

Comment: Keep in mind that you get punished for using .Net - its startup time counts against your addin even if no code is executed in your code.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko For VSTO add-ins, you can have your installer add a key to Outlook's "DoNotDisableAddinList" in the HKCU registry store to prevent Outlook from disabling it -- no matter how long it takes to load.  See my answer below on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why your add-in can be disabled by the host application (Outlook in your case).

One of the possible cases is that Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO add-in the host application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Also I'd recommend check prerequisites of your add-in such as platform-dependend assemblies used in the code. They might be incompatible with the bitness of the host application.

Note, you can use the event viewer in Windows to see exception messages that are captured by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime when you install or uninstall Office solutions. You can use these messages from the event logger to resolve installation and deployment problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I discussed in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74076103/20036274), I discovered (through observation of the registry and trial-and-error) that adding the name of your add-in to Outlook's "DoNotDisableAddinList" in the HKCU registry store prevents Outlook from disabling it without the need for user intervention -- **no matter how long it takes to load**.

As of the current version of Office (in Jan 2023), the "DoNotDisableAddinList" is at this location in the HKCU (which is short for "HKEY_CURRENT_USER") registry store:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList
```

So for example, if the name of your add-in is MyCompany.MyOutlookAddin, then you would create a DWORD value named MyCompany.MyOutlookAddin in the above location in the registry and set its value to "1".

Make sure you use the name of your add-in as listed in the HKCU registry store at SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins.

Also, if you are not finding the "Resiliency" subkey folder, note the subtle difference in the location of this folder in the registry, versus the "main" add-in folder in the registry (at first I missed this):

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList
```

versus

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins
```

Also -- if you are still not finding the "Resiliency" folder, then it could be that you have never selected "Do Not Monitor" for an add-in, in which case you can create the folder yourself (manually in RegEdit or via an installer like Inno Setup).

In my testing, none of my users have experienced the "slow startup" disabled message after having my installer create this registry key.